# How to judge isInstance(ArrayList<>) in java

Tags: java, list

How to judge whether a variable is an ArrayList in Java? Like the isInstance function.

Comment: `"Like the isInstance function."` -- Do you mean the `instanceof` operator? Use of this often suggests that there may be a code smell, that the issue may in fact be an XY Problem and that the best solution is to solve with another route entirely. Consider telling us us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `instanceof`, blow is very simple example how to detect a variable is ArrayList:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

if (strings instanceof ArrayList) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.getClass().getName()` - will give you the type of the value of the variable, but not the variable's type.

`boolean b = a instanceof String` - will give you whether or not it is an instance of a specificclass.

I took this information from: How know a variable type in java?

This can happen. I'm trying to parse a String into an int and I'd like to know if my `Integer.parseInt(s.substring(a, b)` is kicking out an int or garbage before I try to sum it up.